# Use PHP cURL to download and Excel file

Tags: php, curl

I've been trying for a few days to be able to call a url on a remote server that automatically downloads an Excel file when you put the url into a browser. I made a page locally that automatically downloads the file for testing, but I cannot get cURL to do it. The script returns no errors and says it was successful, but the file it writes to becomes corrupt and opens blank.

Here is the code...

```
$output_file = 'E:\Downloads\Export.xlsx';
$download_url = 'http://localhost/test/urlexport.php';

$ch = curl_init();
$out = fopen($output_file, 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $download_url);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
fwrite($out, $output);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

if(curl_errno($ch)){
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

I've spent quite a bit of time researching this but have yet to find an answer that actually works. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [curl_getinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) have a look that. Maybe have a look at the comments in the php page.

Comment: Why are you using `curl_setopt($ch, CUSTOMREQUEST, 'OPTIONS')`?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CUSTOMREQUEST, 'OPTIONS') was one of the things I tried and made no difference, ignore it.

Comment: Why should we ignore it?  It's in the code that you're showing and saying doesn't work.  What else should we ignore?  We can only help debug what you show us.  If this isn't the problematic code, please show us what is.

Comment: "automatically downloads an Excel file when you put the url into a browser" may be the key. Is it possible that the site is triggering the download using javascript?

Comment: You're using both `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);` and `fwrite($out, $output);`.  This seems redundant and could quite possibly explain the corrupted file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure what you're doing - keep it simple.
Here's the simplest possible way to do what you're doing, which is downloading a file and then saving it to disk.

```
<?php
$output_file = 'E:\Downloads\Export.xlsx';
$download_url = 'http://localhost/test/urlexport.php';

$file = file_get_contents($download_url);
file_put_contents($output_file, $file);
```

If this doesn't work then your download url isn't doing what you think it's doing. Take a look at what's actually in the $output_file (open it in a text editor) - maybe it's some html.

Comment: file_put_contents doesn't work as the url is on another domain running SSL. That's a whole other rabbit hole. Right now, I'm just trying to get the excel file working.